# SQL Sort three columns together - day, month, year

Tags: sql

Is there a way to write an SQL order by query to sort three columns(day,month,year) together not individually. This seems tricky because 2 12 2016 should come before 1 12 2017 if in ascending order. 
How do I go about this?

Comment: what is the dbms you are using?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  And why aren't you storing that information in a proper `date` column?

Comment: Mine. Just realized immediately after posting that I can just reverse the columns - order by year,month,day. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just include three keys in the `order by`:

```
order by year, month, day
```

Note:  These are ANSI standard keywords (think `extract()`).  Hence, they are poor choices for column names.

Answer (score 2):

An `order by` clause can contain more than one column

```
order by year, month, day
```